# React Native doesn't show where the error is happening

Tags: react-native

I understand that my code is trying to run the `filter` function on a `null` variable, the problem is I use `filter` in many instances. Why is the info shown on the screenshot not useful at all? The "Source" that it shows is on the server itself, it is not code that is part of my project. For certain errors it will behave correctly and show the source where the error is being caused, but in some cases as in the screenshot below, it is not helpful at all.

My question is, is there something I'm doing that causes React Native to not be able to show me where the error is happening, or is this something I have to live with and go over all the places where I use `filter` and see what's happening?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is a `react-query` error: it means that the library is not handling this error properly

Comment: Are you calling `new QueryObserver()` somewhere ?

Comment: @devpolo no I'm never calling that.

Comment: Are you using react-query?

Comment: @devpolo yes I am

Comment: Can you share a `useQuery` call? The one you are using on the screen where the warning is showing up?

Comment: The problem is I'm using `useQUery` everywhere. i understand it's a query issue, the question I'm raising is why wouldn't it tell me which query is causing the issue rather than show me where the error is thrown on the library's side.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, the library is not handling the error properly. Do you need help to figure out why this warning is showing up?

Comment: @devpolo I actually just found which query is causing the problem by using optional chaining on all instances where I'm using `.filter` until I saw the error go away. Very annoying though. Thanks for offering to help.